# The @supports CSS at-rule is not working properly

Tags: css, ios, bootstrap-4, webkit

In iOs devices `background-attachment: fixed;` does not work so i found a work around by using `@supports` CSS rule.

It worked properly in the testground site but when i tried to apply it to the main site css it didnt work.

In the testground site i applied it directly into the `<head>` the following way:

```
<style>
.paral2 {
    min-height: 300px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: auto;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
.paral2 {
    min-height: 300px;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: auto;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
}
</style>
```

But in the main site i had to use (per client requirement) the `style.css` file and so i applied it like this:

```
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
.paral {
    min-height: 300px;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: auto;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
}

.paral {
min-height: 300px;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: auto;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And it doesnt work, i got no idea why, im completely lost.

Might be relevant, in the `style.css` file the `@supports` rule and its following elements look weird see the below picture:

[image]

Only the first element inside the `.paral` class gets colored in yellow.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated and as always thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the `@support` rule was working perfectly the issue was clearing the cache of the phones, if i didnt clear the whole history of the phone the changes never fully applied, i feel silly but at least it got solved.